# Cannot insert string into a MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert a string into a SQL table, but the string value is blank after the insert. What am I doing wrong and what should I do to fix it?

This is the python function I am running.

```
def newCharacter(usr):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO stats (user, level, exp, hp, attack, luck, aggro, hpregen) VALUES ('{}', 1, 0, 100, 10, 50, 50, 0)".format(usr))
```

Below is an example of my `stats` table after inserting two rows using the above `newCharacter` function. The first column (which is blank below) should contain a string (e.g. "Username").

```
     |     1 |   0 | 100 |     10 |   50 |    50 |       0 |
     |     1 |   0 | 100 |     10 |   50 |    50 |       0 |
```

Comment: Can you please add to your question a specific error message, or the results you received and explain how they differ from what you expected?

Comment: May be default auto-commit is turned off and you need to do `cursor.commit()`

Comment: What is the value of `usr`?

Comment: A string, there are various strings that it could be.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's wrong, but what you've written is vulnerable to a [SQL injection attack](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15). Anything of the form "make a SQL query by concatenating variables together" (and `.format` counts as concatenating) is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

Instead, [pass the variables in as parameters to `.execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15).

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO stats (user, level, exp, hp, attack, luck, aggro, hpregen) VALUES (?, 1, 0, 100, 10, 50, 50, 0)", usr)
```

There's [several different types of parameter styles](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle), it might not be `?`.

Comment: Oh thank you, how would you recommend I add a variable to the table then?

Comment: @ZodiacV1 Just like I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking it's important to sanitize your input to the database when it comes from a user. If users can input whatever they like you may find control characters and syntactically meaningful input. This is even if you have client-side validation.

The MySQL drivers you're using implement this pretty easily:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO stats (user, level, exp, hp, attack, luck, aggro, hpregen) VALUES (%s, 1, 0, 100, 10, 50, 50, 0)", usr)
```

This will allow you to "escape" problematic characters. It will also ensure the value interpolated there is properly quoted, which, I imagine is your problem.